# Symmetry transformations: a doubt about the relations that we assume true

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, symmetry

When we deal with symmetry transformations in quantum mechanics we assume true that, 
If before the symmetry transformation we have this 
$ \hat A | \phi_n \rangle  = a_n|\phi_n \rangle,$
and after the symmetry transformation we have this 
$ \hat A' | \phi_n' \rangle  = a_n'|\phi_n' \rangle,$
then $a_n'=a_n$. 
I think the reason for this relation is that $\hat A$ and $\hat A'$ are equivalent observables (for example the energy in two different frame of references).

The problem is that, if $\hat A=\hat X$ where $\hat X$ is the position operator, then this relation seems wrong, because we would have:
$ \hat X | x \rangle  = x|x \rangle$ and
$ \hat X' | x' \rangle  =x|x' \rangle$ both ture, 
that means that the position eigenstate seen by two different frames of references is seen in the same coordinates. How can this be true if the systems are for example translated one to the other?

Comment: I have never assumed the things you claim "we" assume here. Can you give a reference for these claims? Usually the definition of a symmetry transformation is just one that leaves the Hamiltonian invariant.

Comment: yes, quantum mechanics a modern development by Leslie E. Ballentine. The beginning of chapter 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is not an assumption, it is a requirement for consistency. The symmetry transformation acts on operators and states, it does not act on numbers. So the equation $A\lvert \psi_n \rangle = a_n\lvert \psi_n\rangle$ simply becomes $A'\lvert \psi_n'\rangle = a_n\lvert \psi_n'\rangle$ after applying the transformation. This equation must be true for any linear transformation on the space of states, regardless of whether it is a symmetry or not.
2. So when the transformation is a translation by $a$, it acts as $\hat{x}\mapsto \hat{x} - a$ on the position operator and $\lvert x\rangle \mapsto \lvert x + a\rangle$ on its eigenstates. The equation $\hat{x}\lvert x\rangle = x\lvert x\rangle$ becomes $(\hat{x}-a)\lvert x + a\rangle = x\lvert x + a\rangle$. There is nothing inconsistent about this - note that the transformed equation does not claim that $\lvert x + a\rangle$ would be a position eigenstate with eigenvalue $x$, but instead says that $\lvert x + a\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat{x}-a$ with eigenvalue $x$.

Comment: Sorry, if you define $A' = U A U^\dagger$ and $|\psi'_n\rangle = U |\psi_n\rangle$, then the equation does not hold for *any* linear transformation but only for the ones that satisfy $U^{\dagger} U = 1$, i.e. the unitary ones. If you defined it directly by putting a $U^{-1}$ in place of $U^\dagger$, then it is defined only for invertible linear transformations.

Comment: @MannyC ...but why would I define $A' = UAU^\dagger$? $A' \mapsto UAU^{-1}$ is the natural (adjoint) way for one (invertible) linear operator to act on another.

Comment: Fair enough. But still, it needs to be invertible

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the physical meaning of the operator $\hat A $ before and after a symmetry transformation. My current understanding is that assuming a passive point of view (in which the transformation is a change of the frame of reference) than in $\hat A$ there are the informations about the possible results of a certain kind of measurement (es position, energy and so on..) on the system and in $\hat A’$ there are the informations about the possible results of the same kind of measurement  but from another frame of reference. Is that wrong?

Comment: @SimoBartz Well, measuring $\hat{x} - a$ in the primed frame *is* the same measurement as measuring $\hat{x}$ in the unprimed frame. It seems to me that you expected $\hat{x}'$ to measure position from the viewpoint of the primed frame but that's simply not what it does.

Comment: What is the physical meaning of transforming an operator with a symmetry transofrmation that correspond to a change in the frame of reference then?

Answer (score 1):

A symmetry transformation leaves the scalar products invariant, therefore
$$
a_n = \langle \phi_n| A |\phi_n\rangle = \langle \phi'_n|A'|\phi'_n\rangle = a_n'\,.
$$
It is not a contradiction with the position operator because you are measuring a transformed position in a transformed frame. Let me put it this way: suppose $x$ is the origin, so when you measure it with $X$ you get zero. Then make a translation to a frame where the origin is $x'=\vec{a}$. If you measure the position $\vec{a}$ in the *new* frame, you still get zero, because that's the origin in that frame.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit to the answer of @MannyC using explicitly the translation operator:
If $T(a)$ is such that $T(a)\vert x\rangle = \vert x'\rangle = \vert x+a\rangle$, then $T(a) \hat x T^{-1}(a)=\hat x'=\hat x-a\hat 1$ so that
\begin{align}
x'=\langle\hat x'\vert\ \hat x'\vert  x'\rangle &=
\langle x\vert T^{-1}(a) T(a) \hat x T^{-1}(a) T(a)\vert x\rangle 
=\langle x\vert \hat x \vert x\rangle = x\, , \\
&=\langle x+a\vert (\hat x-a\hat 1)\vert x+a\rangle=
\langle x+1\vert  x+a\rangle\left(x+a -a\right)=x
\end{align}
What this tells you is that the average value of the translated position operator in the translated basis is the same as the average value of the original position operator in the original basis.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the confusion it can be beneficial to think about QM in terms of Linear Algebra. Your operators are just matrices and your states vectors.

If you act with a matrix on it's eigenvector, you get out the corresponding eigenvalue to the eigenvector. If you transform your matrix and eigenvector into a different basis, you will still get the same eigenvalue, as the eigenvalues are more general than the representation of the matrix and vector in a certain basis.