# Physical meaning of the operator under symmetry transformations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, symmetry

A symmetry transformation is a transformation on the states that can be seen as $$|\phi\rangle'=\hat U |\phi\rangle$$ Then imagine we have an observable $\hat A$ and a state $|\phi\rangle$ such that $\hat A |\phi\rangle=a|\phi\rangle$, if we search for the operator $\hat A'$ such that $\hat A'|\phi\rangle'=a|\phi\rangle'$ we find that $$\hat A'=\hat U \hat A \hat U^{-1}$$ I've seen many times that the operator $\hat A'$ is referred to as the operator $\hat A$ after the symmetry transformation, but I don't understand what is its physical meaning.

For example if $\hat A=\hat P_x$ is the momentum operator along the $x$-axis and the symmetry transformation is a clock-wise rotation of $\frac \pi2$ around the $z$-axis, then the state $|\phi\rangle$ that satisfies $\hat P_x|\phi\rangle=p|\phi\rangle$ will (after the rotation) become $|\phi\rangle'=\hat U|\phi\rangle$ that satisfies $\hat P_x'|\phi\rangle'=p|\phi\rangle'$, that means that the meaning of $\hat P_x'$ is the momentum operator along the inverse direction of the $y$-axis.

Is it correct? Does this mean that the operator $\hat A$ and the operator $\hat A'=\hat U \hat A \hat U^{-1}$ can have different meanings? If yes, what's the physical meaning of $\hat A$ and $\hat A'=\hat U \hat A \hat U^{-1}$ after the transofrmation in the case in which $\hat A$ is a generic observable?

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540128) question might be related. Not a duplicate, but related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have a device that measures horizontal distance, I can rotate it $90^\circ$ to obtain a device that measures vertical distance.

An "observable" can be regarded as an abstract representation of a measuring device, specifying only what it measures, without specifying any details of how the device works. In this example, the transformation $A'=UAU^{-1}$ is simply rotating that abstract measuring device. So yes, $A'$ and $A$ have different meanings, in the sense that they're measuring different things — but they're related to each other by symmetry, just like the horizontal and vertical distance-measuring devices are related to each other by symmetry.

If the measuring device *and* the object that you're measuring are both rotated in the same way, then the results should be the same as if neither had been rotated. That's why the rule $A'=UAU^{-1}$ for transforming observables is related to the rule $|\phi\rangle'=U|\phi\rangle$ for transforming states in the way you described.

Comment: If $\hat A$ is a generic observable what's the physical meaning of $\hat A$ and $\hat U \hat A \hat U^{-1}$ after the transformation? I think $\hat A$ maintain its meaning and $\hat U \hat A \hat U^{-1}$ become the original observable but measured with a rotated measuring device. Does this mean that if I measure something scalar then $\hat A$=$\hat A'$?

Comment: @SimoBartz Right: $A$ maintains its meaning and $UAU^{-1}$ corresponds to the rotated device (if $U$ is a rotation -- there are other types of transformation, too). Even if $A$ is a scalar, that doesn't necessarily mean that it's invariant under rotations. For example, in quantum field theory, observables are associated with regions of space (just like real detectors sit in specific regions of space), and a rotation about one point can "move" an observable associated with some faraway point to a different faraway point, even if that observable is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

After a $\frac\pi2$ rotation along the $z$ axis, the $x$ axis coincides with the $y$ axis. Note that we are considering a passive transformation, that is, we are just changing coordinates but keeping all the physical quantities, like vectors and more general tensors untransformed. Therefore, what was previously the $y$ component of, say $\mathbf p$, is now its $x$ component. A conjugation by a unitary is the way a (passive) transformation is translated into the operators of a quantum mechanical system. That is, we can find a unitary $U$ that takes $P_y$ onto $P_x$, viz.

$$P_x = U^{-1}P_yU$$

This shows that, whilst $P_x$ and $P_y$ are measuring different things (that is, different components of a vector quantity), they are related by a conjugacy. In a sense, they are operators of the same nature, the difference being, in this case, the orientation of your frame of reference. We have seen that, by rotating it, you can change $P_y$ into $P_x$.